# Rails Ransack - How to search multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ransack

Using the Ransack gem I was able to implement a search using checkboxes for certain values. However, this doesn't work with more than one checkbox. What am I missing?

View:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  Part Time:<%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_cont]", value = "Part time" %></br>
  Full Time:<%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_cont]", value = "Full time" %></br>
  <%= f.submit "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

Index Action:

```
def index
  @search = Job.search(params[:q])
  @jobs = @search.result
 end
```

Comment: What SQL query does ransack generate? and what params do you see in log, when submit search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view will always send only one value in **params[:q][:job_type_cont]**
it will be a string with either **Part time** or **Full time**
For receiving multiple values, you need to change it to an array (You need to change checkbox name attribute) as follows

```
Part Time: <%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_cont][]", "Part time" %></br>
Full Time: <%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_cont][]", "Full time" %>
```

With above implementation, in controller **params[:q][:job_type_cont]** will be an array with selected values from the view

Comment: Should the index action stay the same? Adding the array in the view rendered a search that wouldn't show any results no matter what was checked.

Comment: Yes you need to change query in index action as well
Refer this document for query 
https://github.com/ernie/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching#in

Comment: Kalpesh - Thanks for your help. I'm really stumped on the controller though. What change do I need to do to my index action to get this to work?

Comment: Can you share your table structure? or Can you list down the column names of your jobs table?

if you have job_type as attribute in your table, and you want to search based on job_type

then you can write this in controller.


Job.search(job_type_in: params[:q][:job_type_cont])

Comment: So your controller code will be something like

def index
  @ search = Job.search(job_type_in: params[:q][:job_type_cont])
  @ jobs = @ search.result
end

OR

you can directly write down it as

def index
    @ jobs = Job.search(job_type_in: params[:q][:job_type_cont]).result
end

Answer (score 2):

Kalpesh suggests

```
Part Time: <%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_cont][]", "Part time" %></br>
Full Time: <%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_cont][]", "Full time" %>
```

with

```
@search = Job.search(job_type_in: params[:q][:job_type_cont])
@jobs = @ search.result
```

which is really a roundabout way of saying:

```
Part Time: <%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_in][]", "Part time" %></br>
Full Time: <%= check_box_tag "q[job_type_in][]", "Full time" %>
```

that way there's no need for funny business in your controller:

```
@search = Job.search(params[:q])
```