# Adding a filter with Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ransack

I am new to Ransack but I can't why I can't do this - I just can't figure out how.  I have a table of results.  I want to be able to filter them.  A simple drop down with checkboxes and the options for example:

- apples
- orange
- bananas

I can build the drop down etc. and have it submit the get or post request I just can't figure out the format.  I tried:

`http://localhost:3000/fruit?&q[type_eq]=apples&q[type_eq]=oranges`

but all I get back is the oranges i.e. the last params request.  This was my guess.  I want apples or oranges returned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails Ransack - How to search multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19829848/rails-ransack-how-to-search-multiple-values)

Comment: Right now you are building Hash and with a Hash if the same key exists the new one overwrites the old one have you tried `http://localhost:3000/fruit?&q[type_eq_any][]=apples&q[type_eq_any][]=oranges` this should create something like `{type_eq_any: ['apples','oranges']}`. I used `eq_any` because otherwise it will look for a type field that equals this array rather than its elements from my understanding.

Comment: That's right - add that as an answer and will accept it.  The _any was also the key along with [].  I should have known that [] because it's like a checkbox form.

Comment: It's sort of a duplicate.  If you use `_eq` it fails - you need `_eq_any`